# Selecting separated data from string as singe rows in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of a legacy system with structure and data like this:

```
id          data

1   some|data|I

2   need|to|get

3   out

4   of|the|database
```

I need some way to get this data as single rows in a query like so:

```
some

data

I

need

to

get
```

...

and so on.

Anyone got an idea on how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([id] int, [data] varchar(15))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([id], [data])
VALUES
    (1, 'some|data|I'),
    (2, 'need|to|get'),
    (3, 'out'),
    (4, 'of|the|database')
;
select value from #table1 cross apply (select value from string_split([data],'|'))A
```

output

```
value
some
data
I
need
to
get
out
of
the
database
```

Comment: Thank you - worked like a charm. I had to define the split-function myself as the database is running on an older version of SQL Server, but afterwards, I successfully got the data as I needed it.